# Angular 2/4: How to deploy angular-cli to server with a specified domain

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-cli

I have an `angular-cli` applicaiton. I want to deploy my angular app to server with specified domain like we do for deploying `asp.net` site to `IIS`.

Fox example:

I want to deploy `angular-cli` to server with IP address: `xxx.yyy.zzz.12` and I want to deploy it with domain `http://mywebsite.abc`.

How can I do that? all those can be done in `asp.net` and `IIS`.

Please guide me to do step by step.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Angular-cli doesnt have the capabilities to do this. You might be able to script this. `ng build --prod` and then move it to a mapped directory on a IIS website. But as far as I know, Web Deploy isn't possible with `angular-cli`

Comment: Thank you for reply. I mange to use `http-server` to do. But I have problem with setting `ssl` for the site.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option you can use with the ng build command that will allow you to specify an output path, I don't believe you can do anything with the domain though.

for example `ng build --prod --output-path="\\xxx.yyy.zzz.12\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite"`

Comment: I mange to use `http-server` to deploy.
`ng build --prod` to generate dist folder
user `http-server ./dist` to make angular-cli can access from `http://server-ipaddress:8080`.
But I want the site can use ssl/https. I got stuck there.